# copy contents of static arraylist from different class?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it possible to get a copy of a static arraylist from a different class. I am trying to access the arraylist from a different class and always getting an empty one back. I was under the assumption that we can access static variables directly...

Basically I want to get the copy of the arraylist after something has been added to it. How can I do that?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;        

    public class two {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ArrayList<Integer> two = one.getTemp();

            for (int i = 0; i < two.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println(two.get(i));

            }               
        }        
    }

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class one {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getTemp() {

        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            temp.add(i * 10);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            System.out.println(temp.get(i));

        }

        while (true) {

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Which `main` method you are trying to invoke??

Comment: I will first run one and try to get the arraylist from one into two...

Comment: Java programs will only run a single `main()` method. So you either put something into the `ArrayList` or you get the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Initializing the ArrayList in main method and want to use that arraylist in second class but ArrayList from Class One will initialize when you invoke the main method from this and then you can't use it in Class Two. Make a `static` block if you want to initialize this at the time of get method call

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Two {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(One.temp);
        ArrayList<Integer> copy=One.temp;
        One.temp.add(100);
        System.out.println(copy);
    }

}
class One{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getTemp() {

        return temp;
    }

    static {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                temp.add(i * 10);
            }

        } 
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

In class two's object **shallow copy** is happening so when you make any change in static arraylist it will automatically show in class two's list.

Comment: basically I want to get the copy of the arraylist after something has been added to it. How can I do that?

Comment: where you want to copy this?

Comment: into two's arraylist. I want Any changes in the one's list should be visible in two's list if I keep calling the getter method...

Answer (score 0):

You can access `static` components of any class directly.

In your example, the static `temp` array list is empty. It was not set filled with any data.

When call `one.getTemp()` it returned the default static instance of the array list. In the method, you should have checked if it is filled. If empty, you should have fill it and return.

Ways are many, but this is one of them.